# Grub not showing after dual boot centos & win 7

Tags: centos, windows, dual-boot, grub

I have installed centos 6.8 alongside windows 7 and the installation detected the "other" OS which is Win7 but after the installation finished and asked me to restart to complete the extra steps like username,,,etc when i restarted it automatically boot to win7 as if Centos is not even exist  :o

Please help.. what can i do to fix that grub loader and make it show?

The boot in my Bios is set to "Legacy" i thought i would mention that in case it will be helpful to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the linux grub didn't overwrite the windows GRUB. Reinstall the centos again and check carefully where you put the grub/bootloader. If installed the os using pendrive it is possible that you install the grub on the pendrive. Boot the system using pendrive(in case you didn't formatted it). It will confirm that.

Comment: but it will it supposed to boot from bendrive because it's a liveDVD? so how can i know if this the liveDVD or the actuall installation? and is there a way to fix it using Easybcd? please tell how can i fix it using easybcd thanks in advance sir

Comment: I installed Easybcd on win7 and added an entry of 
Type: grub (legacy)
Name: CentOS
Drive: Selected the Boot Drive of CentOS
i didn't check the "Use Easybcd copy of grub" option

and then clicked "Edit Boot Menu" and made the WIN7 as the default OS

is this setting true? i am just afraid if i reboot i can't also boot the win7 :(